# Which construction is faster?

Tags: php, performance, opcode

Which construction is faster:

```
$a = $b * $c ? $b * $c : 0;
```

or

```
$i = $b * $c;  
$a = $i ? $i : 0;
```

All variables are local ones.

Does speed differs for mulitplication, addition, substraction and division?

#### Update:

Here's some clarification:

1. This is a theoretical question about writing speed-optimized code from scratch. Not about "searching bottlenecks".
2. I can measure code speed by myself. But it's was not a question about homework of using microtime(). It was a question about how PHP-interpreter works (what I tried to figure out by digging google myself but was unseccusfull).
3. Moreover - I did measuring with myself and was a little confused. Different starting values of $a, $b and $c (combinations of zeros, negative, positive, integer and floats) produce different results between constructions. So I was confused.

BoltClock provide me usefull info but user576875 made my day by posting a link to opcode decoder! His answer contains also direct answer to my question. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you compare yourself?

Comment: Anyway, are you sure it is **the slowest** part of your code?

Comment: the first one, but its insignificant, unless you happen to need to do this several thousand times on one page load

Comment: @Dagon: thousand is not enough to get the difference in such case. I vote for 100k+.

Comment: Does a couple of microseconds matter?

Comment: @zerkms i said *several* thousand :-)

Comment: @Dagon: oops, language issues, sorry ;-)

Comment: its amazing what people try to optimize considering what else is in their code.

Comment: @Dagon: because people are too lazy to optimize the proper things (it takes a time to find the bottleneck) - so they "optimize" the things that is simpler to optimize ;-)

Comment: remove all the white space from your php file, it will parse faster.

Comment: @zerkms: most likely, he didn't compare himself because he didn't know how to, or that it is fairly easy to do. You have to know a few things about measuring code to feel comfortable doing it - see my response.

Comment: @Dagon: It's a very bad practice to made false assumptions about people based on question that seems stupid to you just because you didn't understand what's behind it.

Comment: @supernova.ws: to prevent such "terrible" discussions it is a good practice to ask **clear** questions, which contains also the context, which mandates you to ask it.

Comment: @zerkms: Correctly asked question contains the answer. If I'd knew about opcode decoder question should be: "What time cost of following snippets in terms of opcodes?" Obvously, it easily converted to answer. Main result of my question is a link to opcode decoder.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have PHP 5.3, this is faster:

```
$a = $b * $c ?: 0;
```

This is the same as `$a = $b * $c ? $b * $c : 0;`, but the `$a*$b` calcultation is done only once. Also, it doesn't do additional assignments as in your second solution.

Using Martin v. Löwis's benchmark script I get the following times:

```
$a = $b * $c ?: 0;               1.07s
$a = $b * $c ? $b * $c : 0;      1.16s
$i = $b * $c; $a = $i ? $i : 0;  1.39s
```

Now these are micro-optimizations, so there is probably many ways of optimizing your code before doing this :)

If it is not the case, you may also want to compare generated PHP OP codes:

1 `$a = $b * $c ? $b * $c : 0;` :

```
number of ops:  8
compiled vars:  !0 = $a, !1 = $b, !2 = $c
line     #  op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1     0  MUL                                              ~0      !1($b), !2($c)
         1  JMPZ                                                     ~0, ->5
         2  MUL                                              ~1      !1($b), !2($c)
         3  QM_ASSIGN                                        ~2      ~1
         4  JMP                                                      ->6
         5  QM_ASSIGN                                        ~2      0
         6  ASSIGN                                                   !0($a), ~2
         7  RETURN                                                   null
```

2 `$i = $b * $c; $a = $i ? $i : 0;`

```
number of ops:  8
compiled vars:  !0 = $i, !1 = $b, !2 = $c, !3 = $a
line     #  op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1     0  MUL                                              ~0      !1($b), !2($c)
         1  ASSIGN                                                   !0($i), ~0
         2  JMPZ                                                     !0($i), ->5
         3  QM_ASSIGN                                        ~2      !0($i)
         4  JMP                                                      ->6
         5  QM_ASSIGN                                        ~2      0
         6  ASSIGN                                                   !3($a), ~2
         7  RETURN                                                   null
```

3 `$a = $b * $c ?: 0;` :

```
number of ops:  5
compiled vars:  !0 = $a, !1 = $b, !2 = $c
line     #  op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1     0  MUL                                              ~0      !1($b), !2($c)
         1  ZEND_JMP_SET                                     ~1      ~0
         2  QM_ASSIGN                                        ~1      0
         3  ASSIGN                                                   !0($a), ~1
         4  RETURN                                                   null
```

---

These OP code listings was generated by the [VLD](http://pecl.php.net/package/vld/) extension.

Comment: YEY! It's EXACTLY what I need! I didn't even know that this things possible! Which tool or function I should use to produce such results?

Comment: added a link to the VLD extension used for generating these listings

Comment: @user576875: Thanks! Now I really can get answers for such types of questions by myself!

Comment: Wow! It's extension from author of Xdebug!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function run(){
$b=10;
$c=10;
$start=gettimeofday(TRUE);
for($k=0;$k<10000000;$k++){
  $a = $b * $c ? $b * $c : 0;  
}
printf("%f\n", gettimeofday(TRUE)-$start);
$start=gettimeofday(TRUE);
for($k=0;$k<10000000;$k++){
  $i = $b * $c;  
  $a = $i ? $i : 0;  
}
printf("%f\n", gettimeofday(TRUE)-$start);
}
run();
?>
```

On my system (PHP 5.3.3, Linux, Core i7 2.8GHz), I get

```
1.593521
1.512892
```

So the separate assignment is slightly faster. For addition, (+ instead of *), I get the reverse result:

```
1.386522
1.450358
```

So you really need to measure these on your own system - with a different PHP version, the outcome may change again.

Comment: Interestingly if you set `$b = 0;`, you get the `$a = $b * $c ? $b * $c : 0;` runs a lot faster than the other one. So conclusion is, depends on the inputs :)

Comment: @Lionel Chan: Interesting indeed. Also notice that this optimization only happens for multiplication - addition of 0 is apparently not special-cased.

Comment: @Lionel: It probably optimizes it to `0` given one of the operands is `0`.

Comment: (I think) the optimization occurs because for the first block, it needs to do multiplication, comparing and assigning, and for 2nd block, it needs to do multiplication, assigning, comparing, and assigning. Whichever pattern doesn't really helps much in optimization, imo.

Comment: Martin, you are right. One have to know a few things about measuring code. Your test, for example, measures nothing and, therefore, useless one.

Answer (score 0):

Your two pieces of code have a drawback each.  One does an additional assignment; the other does an additional mathematical operation.  Best would be to do neither, which, with the ternary operator in PHP 5.3, you can:

```
$a = $b * $c ?: 0;
```

Omitting the second part of the ternary causes PHP to put the result of the first part there instead.

Using Martin v. Löwis's benchmarking code, I reckon this is about 25% faster than either.

Comment: Well, yeah, only if OP is using PHP 5.3.

Comment: Unfortunatly I need to maintain compatibility with PHP 5.2.x

Comment: `$a = 1 OR 0;` is `($a = 1) OR 0;`, and OR always evaluates to a boolean